# When to use UIScrollView instead of its subclasses?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uikit

Are there any use cases where one would better use `UIScrollView` instead of one of its two subclasses `UICollectionView` and `UITableView`?

I saw one used in a piece of recent code and cannot think of any justifiable reason to use it instead of, in that case, a collection view.

Comment: When you have "static" data to show, just use a UIScrollView or when the Views you want to shot to the user are too many to fit in a single screen dimension.
If you have dynamic data (ie: the number of items can change or you have N elements almost similar), use a UITableView or a UICollectionView.

Comment: @DungeonDev It has nothing to do with whether the data is "static" or not. `UITableView` and `UICollectionView` (and `UIStackView`) provide efficiency and layout. They only show the views that actually appear on the screen at the moment.

Comment: `UIScrollView` has many uses... providing for "pinch to zoom" functionality is one that comes to mind.